# How to remove comma on a for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want to remove the first comma. Is there a way to remove the comma of the loop?

Here's my code:

```
foreach (var field in tablefields.Items)
{
    if (m_datacount < datatype.Items.Count)
    {
        d_type = datatype.Items[m_datacount].ToString();
        m_datacount++;
    }

    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\t,@" + field + " " + d_type + "\n";
    datatype.ResetText();
}

m_datacount = 0;
```

Output:

```
,@id uniqueidentifier
,@title varchar
,@active_flag bit
,@created_by_id uniqueidentifier
,@created_by_system_code varchar
,@created_date_time datetime
,@modified_by_id uniqueidentifier
,@modified_by_system_code varchar
,@modified_date_time datetime
```

Comment: What is `tablefields.Items`?

Answer (score 2):

`Why reinvent the wheel....`

Simply use `String.Join`

```
string result = String.Join(", ", myarray);
```

for e.g.

```
string[] myarray = { "Firstuser", "Seconduser" };
```

So `result` will be `"Firstuser, Seconduser"`,

Comment: its your collection whom you want to flatten.

Comment: The OP doesn't have a `myarray` in his question, that's what @TimSchmelter is saying.

Comment: yeah, I know but the the output I'm getting came from a listbox that contains data from a database

Answer (score 2):

I would use `String.Join`. Since you have commented on another answer that `tablefields` is a `ListBox` this works:

```
var strings = tablefields.Items.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString());
richTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine + ",", strings);
```

Tested with this sample data:

```
tablefields.Items.AddRange(new ListBox.ObjectCollection(tablefields, new[]{"id","spid","charge_type_rcd","name_e","active_status"}));
```

Output:

```
id
,spid
,charge_type_rcd
,name_e
,active_status
```

You can also use a `StringBuilder` which is less readable but can be more efficient if you have many, many items:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in tablefields.Items)
    sb.AppendLine(item.ToString()).Append(',');
if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;   // to remove the last comma
richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: the data came from a database btw. :)

Comment: @user3788757: that doesn't matter, does it? I've assumed that the `ListBox` contains `Objects`, therefore i've used `ToString` to create strings. Note that i've edited my answer to provide a `StringBuilder` approach which can be more efficient (if you have say, more than 1000 items).

Answer (score 0):

[`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method can be used to remove trailing characters from a string:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: it removed all of my comas

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0,richTextBox1.Text.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of ***field2***? It isn't used in your code...

Why use a counter (***m_fieldcount***) if you're using a foreach loop?

What does ***tablefields.ResetText();*** do?

Anyway, try this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = String.Join("\n\t,", tablefields.Items.Select(a=>a.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: @user3788757 why? what type is Items?

Answer (score -1):

```
richTextBox1.Text + "" + t_fields + "\n\t,".Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Lenght - 1);
```

check out also removing the last index. using `Remove(index)`